# PostgreSQL arabic case insensitive

Tags: postgresql, unicode, arabic, collation, icu

I am looking for how to search a database using Arabic text. In Arabic there are some letters that can be written in different ways but in the results they should all show up if one of them is included in the where clause.

The famous example for this would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name = "اسامة";
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  3 | أسامه        |
|  4 | أسامة        |
|  5 | اسامه        |
|  6 | اسَامه        |
+----+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I found a good and probably most performant way to do this by creating a custom collation on MySQL in this [article](https://a-essam.medium.com/arabic-case-insensitive-in-database-systems-how-to-solve-alef-with-and-without-hamza-problem-c54ee6d40bed) but I have no idea how that is done or if it is possible at all in PostgreSQL.

Other ways that include changing the query itself to use Regex are not useful for my use case.

Can someone please guide me how to do the same

Comment: I played around with a table with names like `احمد`, `أسامه`, `أسامة` and `اسامه`, and an indeterministic accent insensitive Arabic collation failed to match more than one of them. There is also no Arabic `unaccent` dictionary. So I don't think you can have that in PostgreSQL, but I understand nothing of Arabic, so I cannot be certain.

Comment: You can create your own unaccent dictionary if you know which characters can be normalized.

Comment: @SimonPerepelitsa I do know what characters I want to treat as same, do you have any references or guides on how to create such dictionary?

Comment: It is well-documented: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/unaccent.html

Comment: I found this link: https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/collation/ar.html This maybe helpful. But I don't know Arabic.